# Pass Parameter between Service Tasks - Camunda

Tags: bpmn, business-process-management, camunda

I have a quick question with respect to passing a dynamic value generated from one Java Delegate class to another.

Complete Steps :

1) I have a class to create a request.
2) Once the request is created, an ID is generated and that ID has to be passed to the next Java delegate to create another request.

Is this possible in Camunda to do it dynamically ?

Thanks
Adam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Process variables are the answer.
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.5/user-guide/process-engine/variables/